# Linux c/c++ How to find PID from a ThreadID

Tags: c++, c, linux, process, system-calls

I'm currently writing a FUSE application that should implement process based access rights. I now stumble about the fact, that FUSE only provides the ThreadID, not the ProcessID. Now I need to find the PID (or Thread Group ID) for the given Thread ID of a different process.

I noticed that the proc fs provides Thread based information (even a ls /proc does not show none PID TID's they can still be accessed through /proc/<TID>/) in this way I can ask /proc/<TID>/status about the Tgid, but as my FUSE app will serve hundreds of requests per second, I feel this might not be the best way here.

Does anyone know a syscall or function of the form *gettgid(tid)* to be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use /proc/ to get this info yourself. I can't find any syscall or posix functions that do what you need. /proc/ should be fast as it isn't a real fs on disk and I think it's the only choice.

Comment: Indeed. Linux contains very few syscalls or APIs to access system information, other than `proc`. Specicially the thread IDs are located in `/proc/<parent_pid>/task/*`

Comment: Additionally, note that on Linux specifically, where thread IDs are basically process IDs, I've had some luck (with some sample code) using `getpgid`; however the return value might not always be the same..

Comment: Thank's for this answer. After lots of further researches, I decided to use /proc/<TID>/status. My performance test resulted in ~45'000 requests per second and CPU are possible.

Comment: I know that i can get the tgid from /proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/status, which would get me the pid. But if I don't know the <pid>, how do i get the entire path in order to read the status?

Comment: /proc/self/status will give the status of the current process

Comment: @sham1810, /proc/<tid>/task/<tid>/status should work.