# Preformant way to get a PID from a TID

Tags: linux, process, task, system-calls

This question is not about pthread IDs, but about values typically obtained by `gettid` or `ptrace`.

Does the linux kernel provide any mechanism to obtain the thread group id (usually obtained by `getpid`) from a given tid in a relatively efficient manner? Something that doesn't require io or parsing?

The only method seems to `open` `/proc/TID/status`, `read` the file into a buffer, scan line-by-line for `Tgid`, and then parse the string as an unsigned integer.

I'm hoping that there is a syscall I missed that returns the tgid/pid given the pid, even if the id is returned indirectly within a some data structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508413/linux-c-c-how-to-find-pid-from-a-threadid Also bear in mind that TIDs can be recycled, so even if you obtain the thread group ID somehow, it may become invalid next moment (i.e. thread terminates, another process spawns a new thread, it gets the same TID). The correct way to identify a thread is with a (PID, TID) pair and not with a TID alone. Of course PIDs can be recycled too...

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508413/linux-c-c-how-to-find-pid-from-a-threadid requires multiple syscalls and parsing. Furthermore, in my particular case, there are proper checks that the tid is what it's supposed to be. What I'm hoping for is something like `getpgid` but returns the pid rather that the group id.

Comment: The point is that there's no such system call. You read `/proc` one way or another.

Comment: That's a shame, please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no such system call. The information can only be retrieved from `/proc`, and your current solution looks like the most efficient way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

just adding to the already available answers. Indeed there is no better alternative on Linux. I was looking for something better myself, and I found this project which was attempting to offer something more usable programmatically:

https://criu.org/Task-diag

Nothing of that however is upstream, probably since too few people seem to actually care about the problem at the moment. It is mostly a concern for high performance OS-level tracing applications and real time, which are just in their infancy in Linux.

An interesting fact, other similar OSes do not have this problem (OpenBSD, QNX, ...)