# How to check if pid is threads or process

Tags: c, linux, pid, kill, proc

To check if process id is exist I check

```
if (0 != kill(pid, 0))
    printf(" not exist");
```

In `/proc/pid/task` I can see all threads id in process id

How can I determine if pid is process or threads in Linux?

Comment: Maybe you can find the `Pid` and `Tgid` entries in `proc/pid/status` useful ...

Comment: @dragosht thanks! , is there any easy way instead of parsing this file in C? that little hard

Comment: I don't think there's any quick function call available for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508413/linux-c-c-how-to-find-pid-from-a-threadid

Answer (score 3):

Read `/proc/$pid/stat` or `/proc/$pid/status`. If the `Tgid` (thread group id) field is different from the `Pid` field, then `$pid` is just a thread id, not a process id. Otherwise, it's both a process id and the thread-id of the first thread in the process.

Comment: thanks! , is there any easy way instead of parsing this file in C? that little hard

Comment: @paramikoooo I haven't tested it but parsing `/proc/$pid/stat` should be trivial with `fscanf`. The formatting fields are listed in [proc(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc).

Comment: How can you see the format for `fscanf` in this link? I want to try it ....

Comment: @paramikoooo If you wrap it in a function that does the `sprintf`, `fopen`, `fscanf`, `fclose`, you should be able to almost pretend the function is a system call.

Comment: @paramikoooo It's at about 20% of the manpage. Just Ctrl+F (or /-search if you're in the terminal) for `%d`.

Comment: Thanks friend , I see what you mean only in `/proc/$pid/status` but no in `/proc/$pid/stat` ,   in `/proc/$pid/stat` there is no way to detect that

Answer (score 1):

you can check the gettid function.

The PID must be equal but the TID must be different in your case.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html